# @mui/material-ui v5.13.3 theme.transitions.create('padding' ... ) breaks node.clientWidth /clientHeight calculation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, react-transition-group, mui-x

I have this `mui` project with `drawer` on the `left` (`fixed position`), and webpage content on the `right`.

[image]

When I clicked the button `Click to hide/show drawer button` it will `hide/show` the drawer with `padding transition`

[image]

When the `mui` `padding transitions` (`theme.transitions.create('padding' ... )`) are bing used, the calculation of the container of the webpage content on the `right` (`node.clientWidth`) will always be `incorrect/one-step-behind`

```
const Main = styled(
  ({ drawerWidth, open, ...restProps }) => <main {...restProps} />,
  {}
)(({ theme, open, drawerWidth }) => ({
  flexGrow: 1,
  // padding: theme.spacing(3),
  padding: "48px 0 50px",

  transition: theme.transitions.create("padding", {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),

  // marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,

  ...(open && {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("padding", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    // marginLeft: 0,
    padding: "48px 0 50px 256px",
  }),
}));
```

If I removed/disable all the `theme.transitions.create('padding' ... )` inside the `Main.js` styled component, then the `node.clientWidth` will return the correct value

```
const Main = styled(
  ({ drawerWidth, open, ...restProps }) => <main {...restProps} />,
  {}
)(({ theme, open, drawerWidth }) => ({
        flexGrow: 1,
        // padding: theme.spacing(3),
        padding: "48px 0 50px",

        // transition: theme.transitions.create('padding', {
        //     easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        //     duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        // }),

        // marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,

        ...(open && {
            // transition: theme.transitions.create('padding', {
            //     easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            //     duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
            // }),
            // marginLeft: 0,
            padding: "48px 0 50px 256px",
        }),
}));
```

Sandbox URL: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/eloquent-estrela-0ux6i9